# SELECT SINGLE FROM @itab vs. READ TABLE itab

Tags: abap, opensql

We just had a discussion with some colleagues about the Title. We currently don't have the opportunity to test it on our Systems, cause the Dev-Systems are being patched right now.

Can someone answer the Question, which of the following is faster, even though `READ TABLE` is much more used:

```
SELECT SINGLE col
FROM @itab
INTO @DATA(dat).

READ TABLE itab ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<dat>) TRANSPORTING col.

SELECT SINGLE *
FROM @itab
INTO @DATA(dat).

READ TABLE itab ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<dat>).
```

I know `SELECT` is way more flexible, cause you can use pretty much the entire OpenSQL-Syntax, but just for these Examples, which will be faster? Does it change if we add a Condition (`WHERE` or `WITH KEY`/`WITH TABLE KEY`)? Does it change with the Size of `itab`?

Comment: Good question. For information, I did a [quick test](https://answers.sap.com/comments/12739788/view.html) for a SELECT GROUP BY which was only 35% down the REDUCE equivalent (kind of READ TABLE). Anyway I would think that dedicated statements will always be faster, unless one day SAP communicates differently. Note that this form is supported only when HANA is the main database, and since ABAP 7.52.

Comment: [the data of the internal table is accessed on the application server and the table is handled like a table in the table buffer. This is possible for all database platforms.](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapselect_itab.htm). Sounds way slower than an lookup via `READ TABLE`.

Comment: This question does not make sense to me. When would one read _some first line_ from an internal table?

Comment: @JonasWilms Its just a theroetical Question. For the practical one i added another question in the subtitle: What if you add a condition?

Answer (score 0):

For a *theoretical question* here's a *theoretical answer*:

The [documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapselect_itab.htm) [states](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abenbuffer_memory.htm):

> The SELECT statement handles the internal table of the application server like a database table on the database. [...]
> There are two different cases here:
>
> - The data in the internal table is not required on the database.
>   In this case, the data of the internal table is accessed on the application server and the table is handled like a table in the table buffer.
> - The data in the internal table is required on the database.
>   In this case, the data must be passed to temporary tables in the database before the query is actually executed.

> Table buffering takes place in the shared memory of each application server. The table buffer consists of a central management structure, an alphabetical directory of tables, and a data area. The individual areas of a generically buffered table or database view are managed as individual fully buffered tables. The buffered data is saved in the data area as internal tables.

So as long as your `SELECT FROM @itab` statement does not contain anything that requires the query to be pushed down to the database, it will perform *some algorithm on an internal table*. Likewise `READ TABLE` will perform *some algorithm on an internal table*. So conceptually - as long as equivalent operations are performed by both statements - there should be no difference between the two.

In reality however I would assume that `READ TABLE` performs some short circuits that `SELECT` does not and vice versa, so whether one is faster or not can likely differ on a case by case basis.

That said, I would *personally* prefer `SELECT` over `READ TABLE` as it is well known and analogous to selection from database tables, also it is way more flexible and powerful.